# How do I position the img to look the same way it does in the figma file?

Tags: html, css, position

I am doing a frontend mentor challenge and I cant get the picture to look how it looks in the picture. I tried making the container position relative and the  position absolute but it makes the page wider even if i put overflow: hidden. I am doing mobile first so i'm trying to get it to go from mobile to tablet size with the media query.

I have the figma file on github if you want to see that https://github.com/JosephCass/e-learning

[Figma Tablet Size Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFF8q.png)

```
code    https://codepen.io/Joseph9384/pen/gOvVdYv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your media query `(min-width: 768px)`**:
Use `transform: scale(2);` and `left: 200px;` on your header-image and adjust the value of left and scale property according to your need. Also you can remove `overflow: hidden;` from header-image as well. Don't use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent div since it will hide especially the bottom left stat thing which you don't want that to happen.

Comment: It still makes the page wider, if you scroll to the right it makes a black bar on the right side

Comment: I forgot to check that, use `overflow: hidden;` on the div container just above the your header tag. I have tried it and it is working.